ПАО Apple / «Apple»
Как правильно?

ПАО Apple.


ПАО «Apple».


ПАО, я так понимаю, это "Публичное Акционерное Общество" - вид организации в законодательстве РФ. А Apple - это название не российской фирмы. Как быть?)

ПАО «Вы́мпел-Коммуника́ции»  или ПАО "ВымпелКом". Видимо нужно русифицировать Apple - ПАО "Эппл" - пойдет?

Вот ещё тебе вдогонку, ответ юриста на вопрос, "можно ли зарегистрировать ООО (Freedom)":

Фирменное наименование общества на русском языке и на языках народов Российской Федерации может содержать иноязычные заимствования в русской транскрипции или в транскрипциях языков народов Российской Федерации, за исключением терминов и аббревиатур, отражающих организационно-правовую форму общества.
Использование латинских символов в наименовании на русском языке не допускается. Допускается использование в русской транскрипции, т.е. ООО "ФРИДОМ", по правилам транслитерации.

